# Replace dictionary CSV values with lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, delimiter

```
X = {"continent": "ASIA, EUROPE, AFRICA" , "Countries" : "JAPAN, GERMANY, EGYPT" , "Capital" : "TOKYO, BERLIN, CAIRO"}
```

The resulted dictionary should look like this

```
X = {"continent": ["ASIA", "EUROPE", "AFRICA"] , "Countries" : ["JAPAN", "GERMANY", "EGYPT"] , "Capital" : ["TOKYO", "BERLIN", "CAIRO"]}
```

Separated each value of X inside the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` function which returns a list after separating a string by a  given character.

```
for el in X:
  X[el] = X[el].split(', ')
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this helped me on my problem.